# ¿Cómo solucionar un Proyecto Laravel en Xamp Not Found?

Tags: laravel, apache, xampp

Quiero aprender `Laravel` y estoy instalándolo.

He creado un proyecto siguiendo la guía
`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "8.X.^"`

el cual se encuentra en mi carpeta **htdocs** de `xampp`

Al ingresar la ruta `localhost/blog/public/` me arroja el siguiente mensaje

> Not Found
> The requested URL was not found on this server.
> Apache/2.4.48 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1k PHP/8.0.8 Server at localhost Port 80

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo o que se procede a hacer?

Comment: ¿Cuáles son tus rutas y a cual tratas de acceder?

Comment: Pues es la ruta localhost/blog/public

Comment: SI pero pregunto tienes declarado el acceso a dicha ruta?, por que de lo contrario lo único que te va a estar regresando es un árbol de carpetas, considera que luego del public deberías colocar el segmento de alguna de tus rutas **definidas por ti**

Comment: Realmente no lo sé, es la primera vez que lo utilizo y no entiendo muy bien

Comment: Crea un ruta simple que retorne un texto y prueba agregando eso en la URL que pones en tu navegador así: **`localhost/tuproyecto/public/rutaDefinidaPorTi`**

Comment: Sería como un archivo simple de php con un echo?

Comment: No, te sugiero repases el enrutamiento básico de Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#basic-routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de la ruta del proyeto ejecuta

`php artisan serve`
Esto te genererá un link que apunta a tu localhost en el puerto 8000.

Con eso ya tienes para ver el proyecto en tu máquina.

Recuerda además generar la key dentro de tu archivo .env

`php artisan key:generate`

Si no la generas laravel arrojará

> No application encryption key has been specified.

Eso es lo que en la mayoría de las veces se procede a hacer.

Comment: Cuando utilizo el puerto 8000 me aparece la documentación de laravel, eso es correcto?

Comment: Si es correcto, tu proyecto se encuentra arriba y funcionando.